# Localhost kubernetes ingress not exposing services to local machine

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running kuberenetes in localhost, the pod is running and I can access the services when I port forwarding:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/my-service 8080:8080
```

I can get/post etc. the services in localhost.

I'm trying to use it with ingress to access it, here is the yml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: my-ingress
spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
              service:
                  name: my-service
                  port:
                      number: 8080
```

I've also installed the ingress controller. But it isn't working as expected. Anything wrong with this?

EDIT: the service that Im trying to connect with ingress:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: my-service
    labels:
        app: my-service
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: my-service
    template:
        metadata:
            labels: my-service
                app: my-service
        spec:
            containers:
            - image: test/my-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
              name: my-service
              ports:
                  - containerPort:8080
       ... other spring boot override properties

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-service
    labels:
        app: my-service
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    selector:
        app: my-service
    ports:
    - name: 8080-8080
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
```

service is working by itself though

EDIT:

It worked when I used **https** instead of **http**

Comment: what is the service type ? NodePort i believe ? can you add the service yaml please

Comment: You need to also show us the Service YAML manifest. `service.name` must match the service name and the namespace must be the same between the `Ingress` and `Service` .

Comment: Can you post what errors you are receiving along with Service YAML Manifest.

Comment: Hello, I've added the service yaml, there are no errors in it since I can call it using port forwarding. I'm just getting the usual "unable to connect" when I try to call localhost:8080/service-url

Answer (score 1):

Is ingress resource in the same namespace as the service? Can you share the manifest of service? Also, what do logs of nginx ingress-controller show and what sort of error do you face when hitting the endpoint in the browser?

Ingress's YAML file looks OK to me BTW.

Comment: Hello, I've added the service yaml, there are no errors in it since I can call it using port forwarding. I'm just getting the usual "unable to connect" when I try to call localhost:8080/service-url

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. It worked when I used **https** instead of **http**